# Change behavior of Alt key in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, macros, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I want to be able to use the alt key in Sublime Text 2 like I can use it on the command line in iTerm. For example, when I hit <kbd>alt+f</kbd>, the cursor moves forward a word, or when I hit <kbd>alt+b</kbd>, the cursor moves backward a word.

Instead, what happens is UTF+8 characters corresponding to the keys get inserted (ex: `ƒ` or `∫`). In iTerm on the Mac, I can change the left alt behavior to act like +esc and it seems to do the trick.

This could either be a Mac OS X problem in general (I have the same problem in the web browser) or something specific with Sublime Text 2 so I would appreciate any Mac or Sublime Text 2 expertise. Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear as to what you're asking—are you looking to edit those two specific key bindings? Are you asking how to change the `alt` key to do something else? Or are you looking for an emacs-ify plugin? Whatever your meaning was, the [Sublemacs Pro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro) plugin should help you.

Comment: Okay I've clarified the question. This definitely helps a lot. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Great! I've added my discovery of Sublemacs as an answer.

Comment: I just wanted to note here that now on SublimeText3 without all my old plugins, everything seems to be working fine without Sublemacs Pro. I think a plugin might've borked it or sublime 2 OOTB comes borked for free. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Sublime Text 2 plugin called [Sublemacs Pro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro) that provides emacs-like keybindings and operations, including those that you mentioned pining for. You can find [installation instructions](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro#installation) and [the complete keybinding reference](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro/blob/master/Default.sublime-keymap) on the [Github page](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro).

Comment: I've had to re-add some of the sublime default shortcuts into my user shortcuts file to make sure I didn't lose existing functionality, but this appears to be doing what I need for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After using [Sublemacs Pro](https://github.com/grundprinzip/sublemacspro) for a few days, I realized it does too much for my liking, although it may be fine for more seasoned emacs users.

I come from TextMate and what I really want is the best of all worlds: mostly Sublime shortcuts, a few missing shortcuts from Textmate's ruby library of shortcuts, and a few shortcuts that Textmate stole from emacs.

So, I figured out how to solve the <kbd>alt+f</kbd> and <kbd>alt+b</kbd> problems:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+b"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+f"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true} }
```

If I find some more really useful ones, I'll post them here. Also, if I find a resource that lists all the possible "by" field values, I'll post that, as well.

Comment: And the changes are pushed to the Sublemacs master branch. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! I had to uninstall it b/c it overrode very useful sublime things. I forget which now, but I'll give it another shot. I can send you the specific shortcuts if you want.